# Multi-language page in php

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I tried to create a multi-lingual page successfully. I used CssFlipper to make the RTL Bootstrap file and all works great except that when I change the language to Arabic, the slider in the page disappears but it works in the English language.
I don't know what is the problem and I tried to solve it but I didn't find the problem

This is the code for silder :

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="sec-title p-b-52">
        <h3 class="m-text5 t-center">
            <?php echo $expr['partners']; ?>
        </h3>
    </div>
    <section class="customer-logos slider">
        <div class="slide">
            <img src="images/partners/1.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
            <img src="images/partners/2.png">
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
            <img src="images/partners/3.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
            <img src="images/partners/4.png">
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
            <img src="images/partners/5.png">
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
            <img src="images/partners/6.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
            <img src="images/partners/7.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
            <img src="images/partners/8.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
            <img src="images/partners/9.png">
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
            <img src="images/partners/10.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
            <img src="images/partners/11.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
            <img src="images/partners/12.png">
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
            <img src="images/partners/13.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
            <img src="images/partners/14.jpg">
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

This is CssFlipper code :

```
<?php 

require_once('CssFlipper.php');
include('lang.php');

header("Content-Type: text/css");

$css = file_get_contents($_GET['filename']);

 if ($expr['direction'] == "rtl") {
    echo CssFlipper::flipCss($css);
 } else {
    echo $css;
 }
 

 ?>
```

This is CSS codes :

```
.slick-slide img {
width: 100%;
}

.slick-slider
{
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
            user-select: none;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -ms-touch-action: pan-y;
        touch-action: pan-y;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}

.slick-list
{
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.slick-list:focus
{
    outline: none;
}
.slick-list.dragging
{
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;
}

.slick-slider .slick-track,
.slick-slider .slick-list
{
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
       -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
         -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.slick-track
{
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
}
.slick-track:before,
.slick-track:after
{
    display: table;
    content: '';
}
.slick-track:after
{
    clear: both;
}
.slick-loading .slick-track
{
    visibility: hidden;
}

.slick-slide
{
    display: none;
    float: left;
}
[dir='rtl'] .slick-slide
{
    float: right;
}
.slick-slide img
{
    display: block;
}
.slick-slide.slick-loading img
{
    display: none;
}
.slick-slide.dragging img
{
    pointer-events: none;
}
.slick-initialized .slick-slide
{
    display: block;
}
.slick-loading .slick-slide
{
    visibility: hidden;
}
.slick-vertical .slick-slide
{
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
}
.slick-arrow.slick-hidden {
    display: none;
}

.slide img {
  height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: `$css = file_get_contents($_GET['filename']);` - Imaging someone passing in the path to a file containing sensitive content (like a config file with database credentials etc), this would read the contents of that file and happily echo it as text back to the client. **Never** trust user data.

Answer (score 0):

I just add direction: ltr; to styles and it worked fine.

Comment: You still have a major security issue that you should sort out asap.